# What happens when an adept gains a mentor spirit during the game that grants power they already have?

Tags: shadowrun-sr5, shadowrun

After checking SR5 core and Street Grimoire in regards to the adept powers gained from mentor spirits. I can't find what happens when an adept gains a mentor spirit after character creation that grants powers that the adept already has.

Example. Adept has Killing Hands and later gains the Shark MS (SR5 p323), which grants free Killing Hands.

Does the adept regain the power points spent on that power to redistribute as they see fit?

Comment: Related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/51417/is-there-a-way-for-adepts-to-swap-retrain-adept-powers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### There are no rules for this.

Normally, when you gain a power that you already have, you simply increase it's ranks. *Killing Hands*, however, does not have ranks, so GM discretion is needed here.

"Spend points elsewhere" is a valid choice, even thought it is [not normally allowed by the rules](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/51417/is-there-a-way-for-adepts-to-swap-retrain-adept-powers), it is [not totally frowned upon alternative by the author of adepts](http://forums.shadowruntabletop.com/index.php?topic=9182.0).

As GM, i would replace *Killing Hands* by another, more appropriate power to a *"Shark Adept"*, like:

- **Improved Sense (Smell)**, and give him a sonar-like sense.
- **Blind Fighting**, so he can find and fight enemies by smell.
- **Spirit Claw**, properly re-flavored as jaws, so they can better fight spirits.

Comment: So it really comes down to talking with the GM about it. Would you have any suggestions for what could be replacements for Raven's Traceless Steps? As I am looking at either Raven or Seducer depending on story progression but I already have Traceless.

Comment: For Raven, i would suggest Voice Control Rank 1 (0.5 PP) or Wall Running (0.5 PP), for Seducer Commanding Voice rank 2 (0.25 PP each).

Comment: So would that be a total of Voice control rank 2 (1 PP) as Raven already gives 1 rank of it? As a side note the adept bonus for Raven is a bit out of line giving 1.5 PP worth compared to .75 to 1 PP for the others so getting a reduced power to compensate makes sense.

Comment: Second link is broken now, could you refresh it?

Comment: @András it's not broken. Apparently, their forum is having technical issues, all pages are returning database error.